# Clearing Eclipse Markers Programmatically

Tags: eclipse-rcp, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde

Is there a way to clear the eclipse markers in the Markers View programmatically?
I'm logging Markers in eclipse Markers View.Before adding new markers,I want to clear the already existing markers for the same project alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `IResource#deleteMarkers()` on the relevant resource: [http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/resources/IResource.html#deleteMarkers(java.lang.String, boolean, int)](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/resources/IResource.html#deleteMarkers(java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20int)) .

Answer (score 2):

Another approach could be clearing the markers by project, instead of resource:

```
project.deleteMarkers("markerId", true, IProject.DEPTH_INFINITE);
```

Comment: IProject extends IResource (as IContainer extends IResource), hence calling deleteMarkers on the project would call it on the resource itself.

Comment: This would be helpful in cases where you want to clear markers from a number of resources simultaneously, Or you want to clear that marker from the whole workspace.